# Tsung Load testing - Not able to do websocket load testing of Openfire using tsung

Tags: websocket, load-testing, openfire, tsung

For load testing openfire with websocket connections using tsung script we are able to make the websocket connections but we are not able to make sessions at openfire.

As mentioned in
http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/user_manual/conf-options.html#websocket-options
we have made following additions in options tag in tcp tsung script with multiple phases

```
<option name="websocket_path" value="/ws"/>
<option name="websocket_frame" value="text"/>
<option name="websocket_subprotocols" value="xmpp"/>
```

Do we need any other changes or additions for load testing openfire with websocket connections?

Answer (score 0):

The Tsung framework does/did not support the XMPP framing as defined in RFC-7395, which is what makes it fail connecting to XMPP servers.

This issue has very (which is tracked as [issue #164](https://github.com/processone/tsung/issues/164)) recently been addressed, but at the time of writing, [this fix](https://github.com/processone/tsung/pull/397) has not made it into a release yet.

Alternatively, the Openfire XMPP server, starting with release 4.7.3, will allow you to enable a work-around that accepts the non-framed communication as generated by Tsung. The issue that introduces this feature in Openfire is [OF-2479](https://igniterealtime.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/OF/issues/OF-2479).

You will be able to test an Openfire server, using websockets, with Tsung, with either solution.